# Invoke a c# function from Javascript Windows phone browser

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser, webbrowser-control

Can i call a c# function from the javascript of an html file which is rendered using a Webbrowser control?
In my webbrowser control i load a html page and html page contains a function callC# which will internally call c# function and pass an argument . Is there any way to do it?In WPF i did with the help of Awesomium webbrowser controland below lines of code

```
        JSObject myObject = browsercontrol.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("myappObj");
        myObject.Bind("MyCustomFunc", true, JSHandler_CustomFunc);

  private void JSHandler_CustomFunc(object sender, JavascriptMethodEventArgs args)
  {
        if (args.MustReturnValue)
        {

           string value = args.Arguments[0];
        }
  }
```

And in javascript call the function like

```
 function callAppFunctionfromJS(){
 var returnVal2 = myappObj.MyCustomFunc(paramvalue);}
```

Comment: No this time a different case. This time want to send few datas to C# code once user click on a hyperlink on HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the `ScriptNotify` event of the `WebView` control.

Let's assume you have got a test.html file in your project folder. Then the code would look as follows:

HTML (test.html)

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
    function myfunc() {
        // this will trigger the ScriptNotify event of the WebView
        window.external.notify("someParameters");
    }
    </script>
    <button onclick="javascript:myfunc()">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="MyWebView"  ScriptNotify="WebView_ScriptNotify" Source="ms-appx-web:///test.html" />
</Grid>
```

C# (Code behind of XAML)

```
private void WebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
     var args = e.Value; // will be "someParameters"
     // Call your C# method here       
}
```

You can have a look at [these samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-81-samples-08631ca7) as well. There is a more comprehensive WebView sample included.

**Edit**: I just noticed that it's tagged Windows Phone 8. If it is a Windows Phone 8 SilverLight application the XAML will look a bit different (see below) but the principle is the same.

XAML Windows Phone 8 SilverLight

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="MyWebBrowser" ScriptNotify="WebBrowser_ScriptNotify" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

To call C# code from Javascript, have a look at 'window.external.notify' and the WebView's ScriptNotify event handler: [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx)

Be sure to set `IsScriptEnabled="True"` on the WebBrowser control and register an handler for the `ScriptNotify` event.
It's this event handler which would load the new content.